# PHP Only Selecting First Row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a quick login form that i made for school the only problem is that when i try and login everything worked perfectly when i want to log into the first user (Username: hbutler Password: password) However when i try to login to my other accounts i get the page refresh which i have set it do if it is incorrect here is my code :

```
<?PHP

//Create the connection…
//("where the database is", 'Database login' , 'database password' , "Database name")
$con=mysqli_connect("", 'root', 'root', "Social");

//Check our connection…
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo " Sorry Mate";
}
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pawd'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM User_info");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$value = $row['username'];
if($value == "$username")
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM User_info WHERE username ='$username'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $value = $row['password'];
    if($value == "$password")
        {
        $sql=("UPDATE user_check SET user = '1', name = '$username'");
        header( 'Location: feed.php' ) ;
        }
        else
        {
        header( 'Location: social.php' ) ;
        }
}
else
{
header( 'Location: social.php' ) ;
}
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Which gets the form data from the previous page i do not know why this is happening and i have tryed changing the php to this :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM User_info");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row == "$username")
```

Yet that doesnt work either any suggestions?

Comment: Stackoverflow does not work so well with "here is my general problem descript" + "here is my code" and then asking for *suggestions*. So take this comment as a suggestion. You need to find your flaw, it's debugging and part of writing code.

Comment: You are only asking for the first result from the query. Try looping through the results. This method also does not scale well as you add more and more users, you will have to loop through every user in your database every time before you know you have an invalid username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that, after your first query, to get the info from db, you are taking only the first row of the table,

`$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

then comparing it with the submitted username, that's why you can't login with any other username, the solution is to add a WHERE clause to the first query,

`$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM User_info WHERE username ='".$username."'");`

then compare passwords that would be easier, but still, there are better ways to do the authentication. but for your example this should do.

Comment: Please don't use user input directly in sql queries without either binding or escaping

Comment: I know that, and I said that this is not the correct way to do things, but still, for the sake of the example, this is sufficient.

Comment: You don't say anything about your solution being insecure, just that "there are better ways to do the authentication"

Answer (score -1):

Modify your code as below:

```
<?PHP

//Create the connection…
//("where the database is", 'Database login' , 'database password' , "Database name")
$con=mysqli_connect("", 'root', 'root', "Social");

//Check our connection…
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo " Sorry Mate";
}
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pawd'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) as count FROM User_info WHERE username ='$username' and password='$password'");
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $result) )
{ //Check for SQL INJECTION
    if( $rows['count'] == 1 )
    {
        //$sql=("UPDATE user_check SET user = '1', name = '$username'");
        //header( 'Location: feed.php' ) ;
        //Other Operations
    }
    else
    {
        header( 'Location: social.php' ) ;
    }

}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You should include an explanation of what you fixed in your answer